# I keep getting errors when attempting to run coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to C# and programming at all, and I am having trouble getting coroutines to work, I have used a basic one before and had no troubles and I am now trying to make something very similar and not having any success.

The error messages from unity:

Argument `#1' cannot convert`method group' expression to type `System.Collections.IEnumerator'

The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(System.Collections.IEnumerator)' has some invalid arguments

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Fire : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform firePos;
public GameObject bullet;
public bool fireCheck;
public float spawnTime;

IEnumerator FireRate()
{
    while(fireCheck == true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnTime);
        Instantiate(bullet, firePos.position, firePos.rotation);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    spawnTime = 4f;
    StartCoroutine(FireRate)();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        fireCheck = true;
    }

}  
}
```

I will continue to research and better understand this but I just cannot figure this out, a fix would be appreciated

Comment: This `StartCoroutine(FireRate)();` needs to be this: `StartCoroutine(FireRate());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not calling your coroutine correctly this

```
StartCoroutine(FireRate)();
```

Should be written like this

```
StartCoroutine(FireRate());
```

Coroutines can also be called using their names as string like this

```
StartCoroutine("FireRate");
```

You usually should use the first variation. The difference between both is explained in [the documentation of StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

> However StartCoroutine using a string method name allows you to use StopCoroutine with a specific method name. The downside is that the string version has a higher runtime overhead to start the coroutine and you can pass only one parameter.

You should probably inform yourself more on coroutines by reading [the documentation here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Comment: Cheers, I don't know how I wasn't seeing that I had even done it correctly previously.

Comment: @OmBiEaTeR It's okay it happens to all of us sometimes.